# How to make that computer turn on by external power on?

Tags: power-supply, atx

I have remotely controlled power supply, and I wish to implement cold reboot with it, for cases of unrecoverable hangs.

Unfortunately, once power is off, computer is not turning on when power appears again -- I still need to press button.

Is it possible to configure computer to turn on if external power on?

Comment: Have you looked in the BIOS under power settings? Most computers have a feature that will allow for recovery after a loss of power.

Comment: It is usually a bad idea to power off the wall power during a hang, hope you know what that does via the OS and file system used. normal power button shut-downs flush caches, write out regestry , sets the dirty bit to clean and all.

Comment: @psychogeek - if the system is in an unrecoverable hang, none of the items you mention are going to happen, no matter how you power down . . .

Comment: Right if the entire system is locked up, not just access to it is buggered.  Even then a hard drive or SSD could be finishing up internal work, assuming anyone would be so quick to pull the power then.